# Find a plane that passes through a given point and contains a given line

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The given point is $P(6,0,-2)$ and the line is $x = 4 - 2t,$ $y = 3 + 5t,$ $z = 7 + 4t.$ Which can be rewritten as $L = \langle 4, 3, 7 \rangle + t \langle -2, 5, 4\rangle.$ Initially I tried to set the dot product of vector $v \langle -2, 5, 4\rangle$ and the normal vector $n \langle x, y, z\rangle$ equal to zero then plug in some numbers to find a value for $n$, I ended up using $\langle 1, -2, 3\rangle.$ I was then going to proceed with this $n$ value to use the formula for a plane, $n \cdot (r - r_0) = 0,$ with $r_0$ having the value of the given point $P,$ and $r$ containing the variable values $\langle x, y, z\rangle.$ This is where I realized that I don't think this would provide an answer, it would merely provide a plane that has the same slope as the given line and contains the point $P,$ it wouldn't contain the exact line given.

Comment: Three points define a plane, you were given one. You can make two more. Then you have the cross product and you are set to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a walkthrough using different points and a different line. Use this to walk through your own question. This should help you better understand what you are doing!

Find an equation of the plane that passes through the point ( 1, 6, -4 ) and contains the line 
$x = 1 + 2t, y = 2 - 3t, z = 3 - t$

Solution:

The points ( 1, 6, -4 ) and at $T=0$ ( 1, 2, 3 ) are on the plane. Setting t = 1, we get another point ( 3, -1, 2 ) which is also on the plane.

Vector a = ( 3, -1, 2 ) to ( 1, 2, 3 ) = < -2, 3, 1 >

Vector b = ( 3, -1, 2 ) to ( 1, 6, -4 ) = < -2, 7, -6 >

The normal of the two vectors is given by the cross product of a and b.

The general equation of a plane is given by the dot product between the norm and $(X-X_0, Y-Y_0,Z-Z_0)$

That should be everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

918796
Take two different values for $t$ -- say, $0$ and $1$. Substitute them into the parametric form of the given line. You now have three points -- $(6\mid0\mid{-2})$, $(4\mid3\mid7)$ and $(2\mid8\mid{11})$.

$\begin{vmatrix}
x&y&z&1\\
6&0&-2&1\\
4&3&7&1\\
2&8&11&1\\
\end{vmatrix}=0$ is the sought-after equation.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the means by which you found the vector $n$ gave an underspecified answer.

You have one point in the plane, $\langle 4, 3, 7 \rangle,$ from the definition of $L,$
and of course $\langle 6, 0, -2 \rangle$ is also in the desired plane.
Therefore the line segment between those two points is in the plane, and the vector
parallel to that line segment is parallel to the plane.

Your desired vector $n$ must be perpendicular to both the vectors that you have already found.